# Como fazer somar em vez de concatenar?

Tags: javascript

### Gostaria de fazer somar o atributo 'Peso' com o valor que coloquei em 'amigo.engordar(2)

let amigo = {Nome: 'José', Sexo: 'Masculino', Peso: '87.5',
engordar(p=0){
console.log('Engordou')

this.Peso +=p

}

}

### amigo.engordar(2)
console.log(`${amigo.Nome} pesa ${amigo.Peso} kg`)

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso é só você alterar o valor de Peso para 87.5, sem aspas.

Aspas indicam que o valor é uma string. Sendo string o sinal de soma indica concatenação para o JavaScript.

Notei também que não há crases no console.log... talvez o stackoverflow tenha retirado quando você postou mas vale a resalva.

Segue o código ajustado

```js
let amigo = {
  Nome: 'José',
  Sexo: 'Masculino',
  Peso: 87.5,
  engordar(p) {
    console.log('Engordou')
    this.Peso += p
  },
}

amigo.engordar(4)
console.log(`${amigo.Nome} pesa ${amigo.Peso} kg`)
```